# One post = one activity

Tags: getstream-io

I am looking to have good feed architecture.

I have users and events.

A feed notification and an event feed. I would like each event update to display a notification to the user. Currently, if I have two events with the verb "update", they end up in the same activity. So I can not tell the difference between the event that was read and the one that was not read.

In the end I need to have one activity per event.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The question is : how can I differentiate each event knowing that they have the same verb. I wish I could put a status read on each event while currently they are all in the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

Ok, I understand, it's working well.

But I'm not sure I have the right architecture.

In fact I have users and events. Each event can have comments.

So I have an event feed and a feed notification.

My need is that each comment on the event, users are notified.

So currently, I create the event feed with a unique identifier and a feed notification with the user ID. Before adding the activity to the event feed, I made a follow. Ideally, I would like if there are several comments on an event, everything is grouped into one activity.

This is the case but in the feed notification.

Do I need to create a feed aggregated ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using a notification feed and want activities with same verb be on different groups.

You can change how aggregation is done by providing your own aggregation format, by default aggregation is done based on verb and date with this aggregation format:

```
{{ verb }}_{{ time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}
```

You can also ensure aggregation to always have a single activity using this format: 
`{{ id }}`.

More information about feed aggregation is available on [Stream doc pages](https://getstream.io/docs/#aggregated-feeds).